# I really no understand why where use Resource

Tags: magento

I really no understand why where use Resource.

I do this command (find and grep), and get file in Resource folder:

```
find . -type f | grep -P '/Resource/'
```

Basically Catalog use

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4
```

Why not is it?

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Mysql4
```

In a few moments I thought would be that it uses EAV, but not, because Customer use EAV and no such this hierarchy.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

One of the Magento "old timers" can probably give some more background on the reasoning behind the changed.  The Magento core team introduced MMDB in Magento 1.6 in order to support multiple database back-ends.  One of the changes involved re-factoring around the resource models, and naming your resource models with "Mysql4" doesn't make a lot of sense if they only support one type of database.  The introduction in the [RDBMS Guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/images/uploads/RDBMS_Guide.pdf) has some more background on this change.

So the short answer is "Mysql4" is old school, and "Resource" is the new hotness, but they both pretty much serve the same purpose.  You'll see a lot of core modules have both styles of resource model.  The `Mysql4` versions are for compatibility though, they just extend their `Resource` equivalents without adding functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The module uses a folder, which was set in config.xml:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <catalog_resource>
            <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource</class>
            ...
        </catalog_resource>
    </models>
</global>
```